# Set width property array dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resize

I have a react table with group fields and resize-able columns.The columns are like below:

```
export const columns = [
   {   title: 'Year Week',
       dataIndex: 'year_week',
       editable: false,
       width: 60,
   },
   {
       title: 'Actual Bank Amount',
       dataIndex: 'actual_bank_amount',
       width: 60,
       editable: true
   },
   {
       title: 'External Incomings',
       key: 'external_incomings',
       dataIndex: 'external_incomings',
       className: "ext-in",
       editable: true,
       children: [
           { title: 'Rental Income/Leasing Income', width: 60,  dataIndex: "ext_in_rental_income", key: "ext_in_rental_income", editable: true },
           { title: "Tax Refund", width: 60,   dataIndex: "ext_in_tax_refund", key: "ext_in_tax_refund", editable: true },
           { title: "Dividends Income", width: 60,  dataIndex: "ext_in_dividends_income", key: "ext_in_dividends_income", editable: true },
           { title: "Licence Income", width: 60,  dataIndex: "ext_in_licence_income", key: "ext_in_licence_income", editable: true },
           { title: "Other Income", width: 60,  dataIndex: "ext_in_other_income", key: "ext_in_other_income", editable: true },
       ]
   }]
```

I am resizing the width in my reducer as below, but I am sure, we can do it in a far better way. Can someone please suggest a better way to do this. Below is my reducer code.

I simple words I want to set the width property dynamically in a function, where I have access to the dynamic "width" and the  "dataIndex".

```
case 'SET_COLUMN_WIDTH':
            const newColmuns = state.columns
            Object.keys(newColmuns).map((key) => { 
                if (newColmuns[key].children) {
                    let Datakey = newColmuns[key].children.findIndex(item => item.dataIndex === action.payload.dataIndex)
                       if (Datakey > 0) {
                        newColmuns[key].children[Datakey].width = action.payload.size.width;
                        return
                    }


                }
             }) 

            return {
                ...state,
                columns: newColmuns
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var col of columns)
{
    if(col.children)
    {
        for(var child of col.children)
        {
            child.width = 123;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about first two elements which  do not have a children?

Comment: Thats why there is an if condition to check if children exist.